# Export email body, import to new template, then send email automatically

Tags: email

I work for a very new ISP and I was wondering where to start regarding the following...

When setting up our customers internet, we get an email from our supplier and then I forward sections of that email to our customer.

My question is, how to extract sections of the email body, import to custom template, then send automatically?

Currently I just copy paste the information manually into a template, just wondering if it can be automated somehow. We use a corporate gmail account, but I was thinking it might be possible to create some form of macro in thunderbird/outlook.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MsgExtract](http://www.maildev.com/msgextract/) to extract sections of the email using Regular Expressions.  The information that you extract is stored on user defined fields and can be exported to Excel, CSV and XML or in your case an email can be automatically sent.

You can find further information about MailExporter exporting features here:

http://docs.maildev.com/article/69-parse-email-data-using-regular-expressions

(Disclaimer, I am the author of MsgExtract)

Comment: Hi there. Cut-and-paste answers are detected and flagged by the system and are in danger of being labelled as spam even if they are relevant. Please be more careful.